# Dynamodb range query on timestamp

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, amazon-dynamodb-index

We have a DDB with a column : Timestamp (string)

Essentially we need to query data between a range of the `Timestamp` column.

What is the best way to do this?

I tried creating a GSI in my test environment using the `Timestamp` column but quickly realized that I will not be able to query a range of this column.

Edit: What I found as the best way to do this so far:

- GSI on an event_type that we know will always be equal to `Update`
- Added sort key as the `Timestamp` column instead, so I am able to query on a range of the timestamp

Do let me know if you know a better way to do this. Thanks.

Comment: Arbitrary range queries do not fit the DynamoDB model, but secondary indexes and `begins_with` queries can get you pretty far if your query needs are bounded.  See the SO question [DynamoDB Timeseries: Querying large timespans of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70536353/dynamodb-timeseries-querying-large-timespans-of-data/70541768#70541768) for some ideas and alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is good. DynamoDB supports dates and you can do your query using "BETWEEN".

A much better, but situational, approach is to include the time range in the partition key. If your time ranges are always of the same size for example 1 day you can do something like

```
PK                             
EVENT_TIME_RANGE#(start <-> end)
```

Then retrieve all of the entires in this time range with a very effective PK lookup query.

If you can't do that but need to optimize for time range lookups you can copy the data into this "home made" time range index.